# Meaning of the phrase "with an edge"

Tags: meaning

What does "with an edge" mean? Here it is in context: "Jack is being facetious with an edge." I suppouse it means that Jack is being excessively facetious. Correct me if am wrong please.

Comment: [Related](https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/197255-with-an-edge) (off-site)

Comment: Can you link to any places you've seen that or heard it? Based on the one example you've provided here, I could only guess at the meaning. It sounds newfangled.

Comment: I have seen it on "vocabluary.com." Here it is: "If someone is being facetious they’re being playful with an edge. "

Comment: That sentence is being used to define "facetious". It's not a common expression in everyday English.